# Is $ a + b = c$ technically $2$ binary relations?

Tags: functions, relations, binary-operations

Since equality is a relation, and operations are special functions and functions are special relations, is $a + b = c$ a shorthand for two binary relations?

First relation being a subset of $\{(a,b)\}$;

the second relation being a subset of $\{((a,b),c)\}$?

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are real numbers it is a plane in ${\mathbb R}^3$

Comment: Short answer: no.  Addition is a binary *operation*, which makes it a ternary (three-place) relation.  Equality is a binary relation.

Comment: How do you make a relation out of $\{(a,b)\}$? Think about what a relation is.

Comment: Ah! I think I get it now. @TonyK Thinking based on your comment: Since a relation is a subset of cartesian product that maps to true, a + b as a relation doesn't make sense?

Comment: Exactly!${}{}{}$